# hadoop how to get distribution cache files in mapper if I use -files command line option

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I run hadoop map red jobs from a remote machine ( windows ) using the command

```
java -jar XMLDriver.jar -files junkwords.txt -libjars XMLInputFormat.jar
```

and submit job to a linux box which runs hadoop.

I know that this distribution cache file will be sent to the HDFS on my remote box ( Am i right ???? )

But in mapper code am unable to retrieve this file name using the api

```
Path[] cacheFiles  = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(conf); 

fileName = cacheFiles[0].toString();
```

Should I use `DistributedCache.addCacheFile()` api and symlinks api, if so wht is the parameter URI I need to mention as I dont know where the files would be copied by hadoop on the linux box?

Also, I tried to copy the `junkwords.txt` file manually to hdfs and specified the hdfs path here in command line as

```
java -jar XMLDriver.jar -files /users/junkwords.txt -libjars XMLInputFormat.jar
```

This throws a `FileNotFoundException` when I run the job on my local windows machine.

What is the solution for accessing the distributed cached file in mapper when passed from remote machine using -file command line option?

Answer (score 0):

```
DistributedCache.addCacheFile()
```

You should indeed add the file to the distributed cache while setting up the job.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. When I use -files option I wouldnt know where the files would be placed in HDFS. So in that case what might be the parameters for this api DistributedCache.addCacheFile() ??

Comment: I am able to read the file send via -files option in command line now. In driver code I added DistributedCache.createSymlink(configuration); and in mapper code I got the configuration as public void configure(JobConf conf) {
  this.conf = conf;   and in map method using,  Path[] cacheFiles = null;    
  try {   
   cacheFiles = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(conf2);

Comment: You don't have to know where it is in HDFS, if you added to distributed cache it is accessible via Context, which is available in every mapper/reducer. If I have to input a settings file to map/reduce functions then I add it to DBCache and open an inputstream in the mapper to read from it.